# Comparing Hashmap (k,v) values "against a String list" - is there a better Scala implementation

Tags: scala, hashmap, contains

I have the following Scala code.  It filters the (k,v) values of a HashMap by calling isKeywordInTopicTitle(keyword).
This compares with a wordlist, checking to see if the any of the wordList is "contained".

```
val hashWithSearchKeywords = readlinks.values.filter(isKeywordInTopicTitle(_))
[snip]

def isKeywordInTopicTitle(keyword: String): Boolean = {
  val wordList = List("engine", "deluxe", "motor", "VW", "EMPI")

  (wordList.foldLeft(false)( _ || keyword.contains(_) ))
}
```

Is there a more efficient way of doing this (which is readable/understandable for a functional programmer who is not an expert)?  :O)

Thanks

Miles.

Comment: Are you sure the above code works?  `keyword` is a String, so `keyword.contains(x)` means that `x` is a character in the keyword.  I'm guessing you want to check that `wordList contains keyword`.

Comment: That is correct.   I do want to check that worldList contains one or more keyword.

Answer (score 4):

Well, I guess that the line

```
(wordList.foldLeft(false)( _ || keyword.contains(_) ))
```

you can rewrite it as

```
wordList exists keyword.contains
```

being the latter more readable.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the use of `collect` over the `HashMap` which leads to a concise code, like this,

```
val hashWithSearchKeywords =  readlinks.collect { 
  case m@(k, v) if wordList.contains(v) => m 
}
```

This delivers the map `(key,value)` pairs (namely `(m._1,m._2)` ) that hold the condition.

**Update**

More of a side comment on concise code, consider `val wl = wordList.toSet` and thus

```
val hashWithSearchKeywords = readlinks.collect { case m@(k, v) if wl(v) => m }
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers address some of the readability concerns. Id just add that provided you use a native `Set` or `HashSet` for `wordList`, then it cannot really be much more efficient.  `HashSet` ensures O(1) lookup.